# Android - How can I synchronize UsbManager::requestPermission?

Tags: java, android, concurrency, synchronization, locking

I have the following code:

```
public final static @NonNull String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "blah blah";
public final @NonNull Object permissionLock = new Object();
public final @NonNull AtomicBoolean didReceiverReceive = new AtomicBoolean(false);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            didReceiverReceive.set(true);
            synchronized (permissionLock) {
                permissionLock.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION));
    final @NonNull UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
    final @NonNull UsbDevice usbDevice = usbManager.getDeviceList().values().stream().findFirst().get();
    // For the sake of requesting permission, assume
    //  usbDevice != null; (and unwrapping the Optional<UsbDevice> was successful)
    //  usbManager.hasPermission(usbDevice) == false;
    // We need to request permission!
    synchronized (permissionLock) {
        usbManager.requestPermission(usbDevice, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE));
        /* CASE 1: assume UsbManager::requestPermission is asynchronous
         * THIS CAUSES DEADLOCK! THIS IS BAD
        try {
            permissionLock.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            // this never happens btw
            throw new RuntimeException(ie);
        }
         */
        /* CASE 2: assume UsbManager::requestPermission is synchronous
         * THIS THROWS AN ASSERTION ERROR! THIS IS BAD
        assert didReceiverReceive.get();
         */
    }
    // TODO how do I safely block execution of the Thread that calls onCreate until the USB-permission broadcast receiver receives the broadcast intent?
}
```

I tried two things (named CASE 1 and CASE 2), which are in the `onCreate` method in the location in which they were invoked.

I was expecting that `UsbManager::requestPermission` was either asynchronous or synchronous. Pretty reasonable, no? It turns out it is semi-synchronous for lack of a better word. What happens is that the `UsbManager` seems to schedule the broadcast/permission request to be executed at some time in the future, but not necessarily on a different thread. This thread that it uses to schedule the broadcast/permission request is the same that calls `onCreate`, regardless of whether or not I put `usbManager.requestPermission(...)` in a new `Thread`. Consequently, I simply cannot create a scenario in which the USB-permission broadcast receiver's `onReceive` method is invoked appropriately before the `onCreate` method terminates.

Comment: Is the use of a synchronized lock mechanism in the USB broadcast receiver and USB permission request required? I have USB connection state codes that do not use any synchronized lock mechanism, as well as its USB broadcast receiver and USB permission request. All of these codes are contained within a sticky Service. It has been operational since API 16.

Comment: However, if you require a synchronized approach, you can refer to the following Github project, which I used to use before switching to https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android for detecting a USB serial adapter: https://github.com/eclectice/android-BluetoothChat/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/bluetoothchat/BluetoothChat